# Adobe Flash to play RTSP stream?

Tags: flash, rtsp

I have a home made RTSP server that streams video to QuickTime clients. Now, I need to support Flash Player clients, because QuickTime needs some configuration to work on Windows, and also there is no implementation of it in Linux distributions. Then I opted for Flash.

**BUT:** does Flash support RTSP??? If not, where can I find documentation for its streaming protocol so I can build one?

Any details on this will be appreciated... thanx!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<< does Flash support RTSP??? NO.

FLASH is a container, flv is for video and fla for audio. Now.. everything below is Adobe's product.

```
Adobe's    ----------------  Adobes's   --------------------- Adobe's
Streaming Server             RTMP Protocol                    Flash Player
```

a) [Adobe's Streaming Server](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/)
b) [Adobe's RTMP Protocol](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/rtmp.html)
c) [Adobe's Flash Player](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/)
d) [F4v/Flv video format](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/f4v.html)

These above software's are designed specifically for web applications to provide end user seamless, secured, uninterrupted, high quality video.

If you want some hands on then you can try [Red5](http://red5.org/) (Open Source Flash Server written in Java) or [rtpmd](http://www.rtmpd.com/) (C++ RTPM server)

Comment: Author asked about Flash Player. Obviously, my 'Flash' was in this context. RTMP != RTSP. So flash player has not native support for RTSP protocol.

Comment: Also RTMP is a propietery protocol.

Answer (score 3):

Flash doesn't support RTSP. For streaming Flash uses [RTMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol).

RTSP [spesification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2326).

RTMP [spesification](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/rtmp.html).

BTW, what about [VLC media player](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLC_media_player). VLC supports many formats and protocols including RTSP and exists on Win, Mac and Linux platforms.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a player for this: [Locomote Video Player](https://github.com/AxisCommunications/locomote-video-player). Disclaimer: I am the author.

Locomote supports RTSP (and RTMP[S,E,T], MP4 and FLV). It uses sockets to connect so a [socket policy server](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/socket_policy_files.html) is required.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do multicast streaming (you are on a LAN, you want to save bandwidth), you should search how to convert the RTSP to RTMFP, because RTMFP is the Adobe's recently "invented" proprietary protocol which supports multicasts just like the RTSP protocol does for a long time.
    IMHO Adobe could just extend RTSP (it's extensible) and just define their specific payload to allow all existing RTSP players to implement it w/o much hassle, but they didn't.....
   A Flash-based player can be made to support RTSP, providing that the RTSP protocol will be handled in an action script library. I don't know whether such exists.
Multicast streams are being sent over UDP and utilize multicast IP addresses like 224.0.0.221 for example. NOTE: Multicasts are not supported over the Internet, thus 're limited to a LAN where the switches support it.